# Передача файла на usb устройство

Tags: c++

Каким образом в c++ можно организовать копирование файла с компьютера на usb устройство (телефон/флешка), подключенный через usb?

Comment: Мда, винда как всегда в своем репертуаре (ОС стоило бы указать в тегах вопроса, потому что в Unix системах любые устройства отражены в файловую систему и там проблем нет).

Comment: А в чем именно проблема? Вроде как появляется соответствующая буква диска, так что копируем, как на обычный диск...

Comment: А если это телефон? Когда подключаем телефон, то появляется не диск, а устройство. Как обращаться к нему, в таком случае?
Что-то вроде: "SAMSUNG\\SD-карта\\" ?

Comment: "появляется" устройство в explorer, не факт, что оно есть, как драйвер. Для, доступа наверное надо смотреть com-интерфейсы проводника.